# How to set multiple label texts to multiple cells

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm looking for an easier and more professional option to pair Widget texts/States depending on the value of a cell in a table.

Say I have a df:

```
             End Time  count
0 2021-09-22 10:20:00      3
1 2021-09-22 10:30:00      3
2 2021-09-22 10:40:00      6
```

Currently I use `x1 = df.iloc[2,1]` to select the specific cell (6), then use `self.label.setText(x1)`.
Doing this once doesn't seem like an issue, but in setting 3 different labels to the 3 values in `df['count']`, the code gets rather lengthy and ugly.

**Main Question**: How do I go about setting each value in that column to an individual QLabel/QPushButton etc. without doing each individually? Widget names do not matter to me.

*Below is an example of how I'm currently using the df, where I resize the label based on the value in `df['count']`:*

```
df['End Time'] = ['2021-09-22 10:20:00', '2021-09-22 10:30:00', '2021-09-22 10:40:00']
df['count'] = ['3', '3', '6']

x1 = groupDF.iloc[2,1]
x1 = x1*20
self.label.resize(131, x1)
```

Comment: You're talking about a table, why do you need to use labels? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I'm using the table elsewhere, I'm attempting to set a label's dimensions based on the value in df['count']. I'll provide more in the question.

Comment: So, you practically want to dynamically create and update widgets based on the contents of the model? While it can be done, wouldn't it be easier if you *actually* used a table to show the data?

Comment: Yep, that's essentially what I'd like to do. I guess I'm trying to do both, I've created this for someone else's use, and they've asked for this addition. I agree with you though, I believe displaying this in the table is the simplest method, but for the sake of their happiness and my own learning, I've taken this route. This knowledge will be able to help me elsewhere with some other projects I've been trying to work on.

Comment: Well, consider that using a table doesn't mean that it *looks* like a table. Also, in order to properly display the data, a scroll area and grid layout *must* be used, which is, fundamentally, what a table is. The problem with trying to dynamically create objects from a data model is that you need to carefully implement widget insertion, update, and possible removal, otherwise you risk having "ghost" widgets or overlapping objects. That said, your current code is a bit vague, and also you should **not** resize labels, as their contents should automatically resize themselves.

Comment: I'm essentially creating a bar graph, the label resizing is based of the count, say a count of 1 = 1px, therefore 2 = 2px and so on. Using the data I posted, I would create a UI with 3 QLabel widgets, each with height dimensions in accordance to the count. I think I understand what you mean by "ghost" widgets or other complications, but I think this comment should clear up that I'm not creating new widgets based on the data, simply dynamically changing them as you originally suggested. I currently use a QTableView to display the df (or one similar), this is simply in addition to that.

Comment: I suppose I could use a Matplotlib Bar graph for this instance, assuming I can configure one, but if anyone has a relatively simple answer to the Main Question please post it! This knowledge could come in handy for myself later on as well as others viewing the question.

Comment: @pipettejockey It seems all you need to do is create a list/dict of the labels and then use a for-loop to update them by index/key.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone curious, I created a matplotlib Bar plot instead:

```
 plt.bar(x=df['End Time'], height=df['count'], color='#F28830')
```

But in the future, for other projects, I'm planning to use a for-loop, as suggested by ekhumoro, where I set the QLabel object name to an index I create in the df:

```
widget = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QLabel, row['Index_ID'])
target = df.index[df['Index_ID'] == row['Index_ID']]
```

I can then setText or StyleSheet of the widget that matches the Index.

```
If row['count'] > 0:
     widget.setText('count')
```